# Algorithms for heaviest edge-disjoint cycle collection contained in graph's set of edges

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, cycles

given a biconnected symmetric graph with weighted edges,
what is the algorithmic complexity of determining a set of pairwise edge-disjoint cycles with maximal sum of edge weights *if there are no other constraints* besides edge-disjointness of the cycles and maximal weightsum of their edges?

Determing such a set of cycles is a stepping stone in an algorithm for determining a heaviest euler tour in complete symmetric graphs with $n=2k$ vertices (which isn't eulerian), which in turn would yield an improved heuristic for the non-eulerian windy postman problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is NP-hard, even in the unweighted case (all weights equal to $1$).
Indeed, given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, deciding if $G$ contains an Eulerian subgraph with at least $k$ edges is NP-complete. 
However, the problem is fixed parameter tractable (FPT) with respect to the parameter $k$.  See this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5746) of Fomin and Golovach, and the references therein.

Comment: In the cited paper I read that it is concerned with *packing* a graph with "a maximal set of disjoint cycles".  My question doesn't ask for finding a set of maximal cardinality, but for a set whose elements have the highest weightsum; that difference *may* imply a different algorithmic complexity, depending on the weights.

Comment: You are correct.  I edited my answer accordingly to the correct reference.